# Response to a reviewer for a duplicated paragraph

Tags: peer-review, paper-submission

I had a mistake in my paper and I had a duplicated paragraph in my paper. Now, reviewer told me that it is duplicated and ask me for a description for the problem.

I have deleted the paragraph but I don't know what to say in the response letter about the comment?

May you please tell me that what is a good sense response to tell to the reviewer about the paragraph. I think that it is not good to say that it was just a mistake.

Thank you

Comment: Was it just a mistake? In the future you should take one last moment to read through the paper before submitting...

Comment: @JonCuster Sure, as I told, it was just a mistake. Now, what do you think about the response to the reviewer?

Comment: If it was an oversight, just indicate that you have deleted the repeated paragraph. Simple and direct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Say that it was a mistake and the extra paragraph was removed in the revised version.

I can not see the need for going further in this issue. You should be pragmatic, I bet that there are several important points to address in your revision and this is not one of them.

Comment: Sure, there is some other comments that I am responding to them. But because I need a good response letter, I asked this question.

Comment: Sometimes the best response is the shortest. :)

Comment: Agree. In particular, you should probably go point-by-point through the original notes, inserting your responses to each. Some of your responses will be long and technical; it's quite refreshing if there are also some that are exceptionally short (my favorites are "Done!" or "Fixed!").